# Value of an integral

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration

I need to verify  the value of the following integral
$$ 4n(n-1)\int_0^1 \frac{1}{8t^3}\left[\frac{(2t-t^2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)}-\frac{t^{2n+2}}{n+1}-t^4\{\frac{(2t-t^2)^{n-1}}{n-1}-\frac{t^{2n-2}}{n-1} \} \right] dt.$$
The integrand (factor of $4n(n-1)$) included) is the pdf of certain random variable for $n\geq 3$ and hence I expect it be 1. If somebody can kindly put it into some computer algebra system like MATHEMATICA, I would be most obliged. I do not have access to any CAS software.

PS:-I do not know of any free CAS  software. If there is any somebody may please share

Comment: Your integral equals $1$. See the proof below.

Comment: I suppose that the round bracket in $t^4\{\frac{(2t-t^2)^{n-1}}{n-1})$ is redundant (the one on the right). But I did not want to edit this, since it is better if you clarify what is the intended function. I am referring to [the current revision](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/371159/4).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I omitted the closing round bracket (which has no opening counterpart), and proved that the resulting expression equals $1$. See below.

Comment: The question was posted also on [math.se]: [Value of an integral in the interval (0,1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3818207). I will add a pointer to this post on meta: [Cross posts to Math SE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2637#2638).

Comment: If it is a pdf, this itself proves that the integral equals 1, "expect" is underestimating.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: I thought the same. Then I thought maybe the OP just wanted to double check, so I went ahead and proved it. It was a fun exercise.

Comment: @FedorPetrov what pdf is it? (any name)

Comment: @vidyarthi I do not know, that's the OP claim.

Comment: @FedorPetrov oh! I didnt see it. Then wasnt it too trivial?

Comment: @vidyarthi: Probability density functions have integral $1$ on $\mathbb{R}$. However, the OP did not explain why the integrand is a probability density function.

Comment: Thank u all of you for your valuable comments and wonderful responses.And also  my apologies for cross posting.Actually I do not know how to add a link from one SE to another.Next time i post i will bear the rules in mind. @vidyarthi I know the inegral has to be 1,I only wanted to double check to see whether my calculations are correct.This is the pdf of the range of a certain  sequence of random variables. I am especially thankful to @{GH from MO} for making it elegantly simple

Comment: @sajjadveeri you can create a free basic account through Wolfram's cloud portal https://www.wolframcloud.com/. It lets you run your own Mathematica notebooks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The integral can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
I&=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\int_0^1\frac{t^{n-2}(2-t)^{n+1}-t^{2n-1}}{n+1}-\frac{t^n(2-t)^{n-1}-t^{2n-1}}{n-1}\,dt\\[6pt]
&=\frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\int_0^1\frac{t^{n-2}(2-t)^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{t^n(2-t)^{n-1}}{n-1}\,dt.
\end{align*}
Integrating by parts, we obtain
$$\int_0^1\frac{t^{n-2}(2-t)^{n+1}}{n+1}\,dt=\frac{1}{n^2-1}+\int_0^1\frac{t^{n-1}(2-t)^n}{n-1}\,dt.$$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
I&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{n}{2}\int_0^1t^{n-1}(2-t)^n-t^n(2-t)^{n-1}\,dt\\[6pt]
&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1(t^n(2-t)^n)'\,dt=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1.
\end{align*}

**P.S.** You can use [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/) and [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) for symbolic calculations. Both are free.

Comment: It seems that yesterday I inadvertently put a -1 to your answer. the only way to correct is making a trivial edit. sorry!

Comment: @PietroMajer: This is very kind of you, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It seems your conjecture is true. Mathematica gives the result
$$
(1 + 4^n (-1 + n) n \mbox{Beta} [1/2, -1 + n, 2 + n] - 
 4^n n (1 + n) \mbox{Beta} [1/2, 1 + n, n])/(2 (1 + n))
$$
in terms of the incomplete Beta function, and putting in random integers $\geq 3$ always yields 1 (I haven't managed to get Mathematica to spit that out as a general result for arbitrary $n$).

Comment: I proved the conjecture in my response.

Comment: @GHfromMO - yes, very nice, you have my upvote. We posted simultaneously. I considered deleting my answer, but decided against it, since at least I answered the OP's literal request :-D

Answer (score 4):

You can use [CoCalc](http://cocalc.com).
For instance, type
`integral(x^2,x)`
and get
`1/3*x^3`

It also permits symbolic parameters.

Input:

`f(x,n)=x^2+n`

`integral(f(x,n),x)`

Output:

`1/3*x^3+n*x`